# How to map values in a map in Java 8?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8

Say I have a `Map<String, Integer>`. Is there an easy way to get a `Map<String, String>` from it?

By easy, I mean not like this:

```
Map<String, String> mapped = new HashMap<>();
for(String key : originalMap.keySet()) {
    mapped.put(key, originalMap.get(key).toString());
}
```

But rather some one liner like:

```
Map<String, String> mapped = originalMap.mapValues(v -> v.toString());
```

But obviously there is no method `mapValues`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a duplicate. Sorry.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You need to stream the entries and collect them in a new map:

```
Map<String, String> result = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> String.valueOf(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: I like this much better, and it's even one line (technically). +1

Comment: Please note the answer to the linked duplicate includes an alternative solution using Guava: `Map<String, String> byNameMap = Maps.transformValues(people, Person::getName);` "which wraps the original Map and does the conversion when you do the get, meaning you only pay the conversion cost when you actually consume the value. "

Answer (score 30):

The easiest way to do so is:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> mapped = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> String.valueOf(entry.getValue())));
```

What you do here, is:

1. Obtain a `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`
2. Collect the results in the resulting map:

   1. Map the entries to their key.
   2. Map the entries to the new values, incorporating `String.valueOf`.

The reason you cannot do it in a one-liner, is because the `Map` interface does not offer such, the closest you can get to that is `map.replaceAll`, but that method dictates that the type should remain the same.

Comment: this answer is incorrect because it misunderstood the original question, specifically the purpose of the first line in the question, `Map<String, String> mapped = new HashMap<>();`. the accepted answer does not misunderstand the question and shows how this can, in fact, be done in one line.

Comment: @StephenHarrison That is incorrect. We both have conceptually the same answers. I only show the `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();` to indicate the source of the original map.

Comment: your code creates an empty Map `map` and a `stream()` on the `entrySet`, which is guaranteed to be empty. your code as-is creates 2 maps `Map<String, Integer>` and `Map<String, String>` both empty. run your code to find out why.

Comment: @StephenHarrison I am aware of that. I am adding the empty map part to indicate that there is a source of the output map. You cannot write a code samply and have an undefined variable in it.

Comment: @StephenHarrison I even explain that in my comments.