# How to map List of objects to Map of values from the given object using java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

How to map `List<File>` into `Map<String, List<String>>` without creating any additional classes using Java 8 ?

Key should be parent file name, and list should contain all children file names.

This would return `Map<String, List<File>>` so it doesn't compile.

```
Function<File, String> parentName = (f) -> f.getParent();
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, List<String>> var = files
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(parentName));
```

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213891/how-to-map-values-in-a-map-in-java-8?

Comment: what is parent file? parent directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a [`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) downstream collector to the group by operation that maps the `File` Stream element into its name and collects those name into a `List`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> var = 
    files.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             File::getParent,
             Collectors.mapping(File::getName, Collectors.toList())
         ));
```