# convert from Map<Object,Set<Object>> to Map<String,Set<String>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map `Map<String, Set<String>>`

```
Map<String, Set<String> result = map.entrySet().parallelStream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```

I want to convert it to `Map<String, Set<String>>` . by grouping the values and swapping the places of key and value.

But this line gives me

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Set<Object>> to Map<String,Set<String>>`

Comment: You need to parse the value from `Object` to `String`.

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23214299/3959856) ?

Comment: Your question title does not match your problem description. Further, you say you want to convert the map to `Map<Set<String>, Set<String>>`, but declare the `result` variable with an entirely different type (and there’s a `>` missing). So it’s not surprising that you get a compiler error.

Comment: @Holger maybe `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Set<Object>> to Map<String,Set<String>>` is the crux of it? agreed though there is clutter in the question.

Comment: @nullpointer as long as the OP doesn’t decide about what to convert to what, there is no point in thinking about the compiler error. There are three entirely different problem statements, the question’s title, the question’s text, and the code example. When I change the code example to match what the OP wrote in the textual description, there is no compiler error.

Comment: Sorry I reverted to my original description to avoid ambiguity and added an answer.

Comment: @Holger was busy working. Checked and answered and accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you've got here is the type of the map you are creating is:

```
Map<Set<String>, Set<String>>
```

not `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

As such, you need to expand the map's values first, for example:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> collect = map.entrySet()
    .parallelStream()
    // Expand (k, {v1, v2, v3}) to [(v1, k), (v2, k), (v3, k)]
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(ee -> new SimpleEntry<>(ee, e.getKey())))
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Unless you *really* need the parallel processing, I think it would be much easier to use loops:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> collect = new HashSet<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  for (String v : entry.values()) {
      collect.computeIfAbsent(v -> new HashSet<>())
              .add(entry.getKey()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example considering your initial Map is Object to Object. Adapt as needed.

```
Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Set<String>> result = map
            .entrySet()
            .parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> (String) entry.getKey(), 
                     Collectors.mapping(entry -> (String) entry.getKey(), Collectors.toSet())));
```

The problem with your code is that `Map.Entry::getKey` returns an Object, not a String.

Comment: I personally prefer `entry.getKey().toString()` rather than casting to a String, but have an upvote regardless. :) Of course, my method leaves you succeptable to NullPointerException (since some implementations of Map can have a null key, and obviously you can have a null value).

Comment: Note that you're not doing what OP wants (you're not using the map values at all).

Comment: Hi @alexrolea, your answer helped me. But like @AndyTurner mentioned It will generate `Map<Set<String>, String<String>>`

Answer (score 1):

Just to avoid the confusion, I'm answering my question. Thanks to @AndyTurner @alexrolea for pointing out the solution.

```
Map<Set<String>, Set<String>> result = map.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> (Set<String>) entry.getValue(), 
                        Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getKey(), Collectors.toSet())));
```

I had to replace `Map.Entry::getValue` with `entry -> (Set<String>) entry.getValue()` and the other one too.

This helped me group the map by values and use them as keys. Thanks @nullpointer

In fact, this also works. The problem is I was not returning the right datatype.

```
Map<Set<String>, Set<String>> result = map.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, 
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```